# Unwind Segue nil argument error

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ios6, segue

I am new to ios development and I am trying to create a simple test app that allows users to record and edit their pills in their medicine cabinet.

I am using ios 6.1, arc and segues.

Background to the error:

So the user has a list of pills in their medicine cabinet, he picks one and a segue brings him to a view controller that gives him information about that pill. He then has the option to edit the info which segues him to another view controller that shows all the current info in textfields which he can edit and then click a save button which initiates an unwind segue to the original medicine cabinet.

The error I am getting is this. The user can edit the info and save it successfully and pop back to the cabinet. But then when he goes to edit the pill again, I get the error:

`*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString appendString:]: nil argument'`

I did some digging and I found out what is happening. In the unwind segue method,I am successfully setting the properties of the pill to match the text in the textfield of the editPillView controller. For example, I have a pill and it belongs to Jay. But then I edit it and say it belongs to Raf. Using breakpoints, I can see the string change from Jay to Raf in the unwind segue method of the MedicineCabinetViewController. But once the unwind segue is complete, I see that at some point, the string gets set to nil in apple's code (probably because arc is deallocing memory because the EditPillViewController is no longer needed and the pill's owner property then becomes a null pointer). Then when the user clicks the pill again, the pillInfoViewController is trying to use the null pointer and BOOM.

I've tried so many solutions to try to keep the string to stay raf such as using the NSString copy method. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do an unwind segue, any controllers from the one you're unwinding from, back to but not including the one you're unwinding to, will be deallocated unless you have a strong reference to them. So, the pill's owner property, if it's in MedicineCabinetViewController, will go away when the controller is deallocated.

There are several ways you can fix this problem. One way, would be to navigate in your app using code rather than using segues, so you can keep references to the controllers you create, and only allocate one if it doesn't exist yet.

Another way would be to have a model class that's a singleton, which would live for the life of the app. That way all the data concerning the medicines would be properties of some object (or objects) in this singleton class.

Comment: This is a perfect answer! Thank you! I fixed it by using strong references.